# SQL DB2 - add leading zero, align right

Tags: sql, database, db2, number-formatting, ibm-midrange

SQL DB2/400

Trying to add leading zero, align right.

```
 NUMERIC     REQUIRED_OUTPUT   
   .0000              0.0000             
  1.0000              1.0000            
   .0000              0.0000             
100.0000            100.0000
```

Part way there...

```
SELECT NBUN62 as NUMERIC ,char(NBUN62) as CHARACTER,                
       replace(char(NBUN62), '.' , '0.') AS ADD_LEADING_ZERO 
FROM Cost_File
```

```
 NUMERIC   CHARACTER    ADD_LEADING_ZERO    
   .0000   .0000        0.0000              
  1.0000   1.0000       10.0000             
   .0000   .0000        0.0000              
   .0000   .0000        0.0000              
100.0000   100.0000     100.0000
```

Comment: What is the data type of NBUN62?

Comment: NBUN62 is numeric  9,4. Note that DB2/400 is a unique dialect. Not even 100% same as DB2 on other platforms.

Comment: Funny. this works:
replace(' .12', ' .' , '0.') , 
but this does not...
replace(CHAR(NBUN62), ' .' , '0.')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `NUMERIC(9,4)` data type you need the function `VARCHAR_FORMAT()` with the format `'99990.9999'`:

```
SELECT NBUN62, 
       VARCHAR_FORMAT(NBUN62, '99990.9999') AS ADD_LEADING_ZERO
FROM Cost_File;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ckdomrzI).

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE` :

`^\.` to catch `.` when it is first character.

```
SELECT NBUN62 as NUMERIC,
REGEXP_REPLACE(char(NBUN62), '^\.' , '0.') AS ADD_LEADING_ZERO 
FROM Cost_File
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/32nHTuxM)